Proof of gradient of $v_{\pi}(s)$ via Kronecker Product
Hi I am reading Mathematical Foundation of Reinforcement Learning by Shiyu Zhao and I try to understand a proof regarding policy gradients. The part is on page 209/210 in Policy Gradient Methods. First I don't understand the equation I marked with the question mark. Next I also don't understand the matrix vector form. I am a bit confused in the order of the entries in the $\nabla_{\theta}v_{\pi}$ vector. I made an example to understand the calculation with two states $s_1$ and $s_2$ and two parameters/weights $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.
$$
(\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12}\\
p_{21} & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix} \otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix})
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_{\theta_{1}}v_{\pi}(s_{1})\\
\nabla_{\theta_{1}}v_{\pi}(s_{2})\\
\nabla_{\theta_{2}}v_{\pi}(s_{1})\\
\nabla_{\theta_{2}}v_{\pi}(s_{2})
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & 0 & p_{12} & 0\\
0 & p_{11} & 0 & p_{12}\\
p_{21} & 0 & p_{22} & 0\\
0 & p_{21} & 0 & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_{\theta_{1}}v_{\pi}(s_{1})\\
\nabla_{\theta_{1}}v_{\pi}(s_{2})\\
\nabla_{\theta_{2}}v_{\pi}(s_{1})\\
\nabla_{\theta_{2}}v_{\pi}(s_{2})
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Would my calculation be correct here?



For the question mark,
\begin{align}
\sum_{a\in A}\pi(a\mid s,\theta)\sum_{s'\in S}p(s'\mid s,a)\nabla_{\theta}v_{\pi}(s'))&=\sum_{s'\in S}\left(\sum_{a\in A} p(s'\mid s,a)\pi(a\mid s,\theta)\right)\nabla_{\theta}v_{\pi}(s')) \\
&=\sum_{s'\in S}p(s'\mid s,\theta)\nabla_{\theta}v_{\pi}(s')),
\end{align}
For the second part, I don't think it is particularly instructive to think in terms of matrices, as that proof only works for discrete state spaces, but here is the idea.
For each $s\in S$ fixed, the gradient is an $m$-dimensional vector $$\nabla_{\theta}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s)=(\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_1}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s),\cdots, \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_m}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s))^\top. $$
Now, we do this for each of the points, which gives a collection of vectors  $$\nabla_{\theta} v_{\pi_{\theta}}=\left(\nabla_{\theta} v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s_1), \cdots, \nabla_{\theta} v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s_n)\right).$$
So, they essentially stack $v_{\pi_{\theta}}$ in a vertical vector of dimension $mn$, so that
$$ \nabla_{\theta}v_{\pi_{\theta}} = \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_1}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s_1), \cdots, \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_m}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s_1), \cdots, \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_1}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s_n), \cdots, \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_m}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s_n)\right)^\top. $$
However, the matrix $P_{\pi}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, corresponding to
\begin{pmatrix} p(s'_1\mid s_1, \theta) &\cdots & p(s'_n\mid s_1,\theta) \\ \vdots& & \vdots\\ p(s_1'\mid s_n,\theta) & \cdots &p(s_n'\mid s_n,\theta)\end{pmatrix}
As you see the dimensions don't add up if we want to multiply it by an $nm$-vector. The idea of the Kronecker product is to ensure that the dimensions add up, so we get a $nm\times nm$ matrix. In this case, we get a matrix with lots of zeroes as you wrote. The idea is that for each $i$ and $s$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s)=\sum_{s'\in S}p(s'\mid s, \theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}v_{\pi_{\theta}}(s').$$
